# Loading a Null String and Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, service, ria

I maintain a Silverlight 4 application. While I was out of the office, the database structure was changed and a table was dropped and its fields combined into another existing table. Now, I’m receiving the following error after I create a new item and proceed to its "summary" screen:

“Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Text
    At System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.set_Text(String value)”

This only happens with newly created entries, not older entries where the information on the next screen is complete (data was converted from an Excel spreadsheet and loaded into the database). So, I’ve narrowed it down this: the child window that is used to create a new record doesn’t have all the fields that were added to the table because some of the information isn’t available when the record is created. A Google search turned up that null strings can’t be passed in Silverlight.

The Summary screen is loaded via ddsSummaryLoadedData domain service. If I don’t include the “new” fields, then the values aren’t loaded for existing entries, but new entries don’t cause an error. If I do include them, older entries load correctly but new ones give the above error.

Is there a workaround to create the empty fields until they’re needed, but still load data if it exists (for older entries)?  Or does the child window need to be redesigned? I’m new to Silverlight and still have so much to learn!

Comment: How do you load the data? Was the domain/model or data access layer altered according to the new table structure? can you adapt the RIA service methods? Do you use MVVM in Silverlight or do you assign the fields in code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're using Bindings to render your view otherwise null values will be handled gracefully, so if you are setting the Text property manually in code, use the cascading operator to verify you are not submitting a null value.

```
myTextBox.Text = myModelValue.FirstName ?? string.Empty;
```